# How do you change the date of an existing Sonar Snapshot?

Tags: sonarqube

I recently was building history using the sonar.projectDate property.  However, i made a mistake with the date and set it into the future (2913-05-29).  Now I can't run any new analysis against the project.  Since this is the latest analysis, I don't have the "Delete snapshot" button on the history page.

So, I thought to simply change the date of the analysis, since it is valid and is the latest.  I've made changes to the following tables which seem to have had the "bad" date: snapshots, events, issues.

```
update snapshots set 
  created_at = to_timestamp('05/29/2013', 'MM/dd/yyyy'),
  period2_date = to_timestamp('05/24/2013', 'MM/dd/yyyy'),
  period3_date = to_timestamp('04/29/2013', 'MM/dd/yyyy')
where id = ${snapshotId};

update snapshots set 
  created_at = to_timestamp('05/29/2013', 'MM/dd/yyyy')
where root_snapshot_id = ${snapshotId};

update events set 
  event_date = to_timestamp('05/29/2013', 'MM/dd/yyyy')
where snapshot_id = ${snapshotId};
```

Strictly speaking, I don't think I needed to do this because it wasn't associated with a snapshot, but I thought it would help line up the issues.

```
update issues set 
  issue_creation_date = to_timestamp('05/29/2013', 'MM/dd/yyyy'),
  issue_update_date = to_timestamp('05/29/2013', 'MM/dd/yyyy'),
  created_at = to_timestamp('05/29/2013', 'MM/dd/yyyy'),
  updated_at = to_timestamp('05/29/2013', 'MM/dd/yyyy')
where root_component_id = ${projectId}
  and created_at > to_timestamp('01/01/2014', 'MM/dd/yyyy');
```

After updating the snapshots table, the GUI loads with the correct information, but I still can't start a new analysis.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project rc-parent: 
Can not execute Sonar: 'sonar.projectDate' property cannot be older than the date of the last known quality snapshot on this project. Value: '2013-06-29'. Latest quality snapshot: '2913-05-29'. This property may only be used to rebuild the past in a chronological order. -> [Help 1]
```

I am now running Sonar 3.6, but was running 3.4.1 during the "bad" analysis run.

I'm looking for options.  Either the proper approach to changing the date or a manual analysis deletion procedure.

Comment: Now that you have modified the database, it'll be hard to help you. The only option is to start from a backup of your database prior to the wrong analysis.

Comment: The SQL I executed was trivial and reversible.  However, when I was working on how to reverse it, I questioned the thoroughness of my first updates.  It turns out I wasn't aggressive enough with my changes.  I added the second update to the snapshots table and that corrected the problem.  I've added my SQL to the post.

Answer (score 3):

For MySQL DB, execute:

1. Get project id

   `select * from projects where name='foo';`
2. Get current snapshot of project:

   `select * from events where resource_id = ${project_id};`
3. First, check if build_date has valid datetime

   `select * from snapshots where id=${snapshot_id};`

   If Yes, (does same for events) run:

   `update snapshots set created_at=build_date where id=${snapshot_id};`

   `update events set event_date=created_date where snapshot_id=${snapshot_id};`

   If Not, run:

   `update snapshots set created_at=CURDATE() where id=${snapshot_id};`

   `update events set event_date=CURDATE() where snapshot_id=${snapshot_id};`

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, the two sql updates to the `snapshots` table did the trick.  It is not elegant, but I was able to start a new Sonar analysis and have everything recorded properly.